# How to write below query efficiently without using subqueries

Tags: sql

Table : A

```
--------------------------
id    alias1
--------------------------
1     user1
2     user2
3     user3
--------------------------
```

Table : B

```
--------------------------
id    parent
--------------------------
1     user2
--------------------------
```

Expected Output:

```
--------------------------
id    alias1
--------------------------
1     user1
2     user2
--------------------------
```

sql:

```
SELECT Id
FROM A
WHERE alias1 IN ((SELECT alias1 FROM A
                  WHERE alias1 = (SELECT b.parent
                                  FROM A a
                                  LEFT JOIN B b ON b.id = a.id
                                   WHERE a.alias1 = 'user1')),
                 'user1' )
```

How to write above query efficiently. I want to get list of child and parent (if exist)

Comment: i don't see any logic here.

Comment: Edit your question and describe what you want the query to do.

Answer (score 0):

(1) If your expected output is as you claimed, then SELECT ID is not going to cut it.

(2) Eliminate the IN clause by rewriting the query as SELECT ... UNION SELECT ...

(3) Eliminate the subqueries in the remaining part by replacing them with the appropriate JOINs and projections.